# Do I need to supply an op amp with more voltage than I need it to output?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have an op amp that accepts +/- 18 volts as the supply inputs, but I only intend it to output +/- 5 volts. Is it acceptable to feed in the minimum and maximum output voltages as the supply voltages in this case?

Comment: Search for "rail to rail" opamps.

Comment: look at your data sheet. If there is a range for power supply you can trim the rails some. If there is a power supply referenced maximum output of the form Vcc -x or 0.x * Vcc you can't trim the rails all the way too your output.

Answer (score 2):

**Maybe**

Some opamps can provide an output which is very close to or even at the supply input voltage (known colloquially as the "rail"). These are often known as rail-to-rail opamps, and are typically slightly more expensive than standard ones.  Normal ones need some extra voltage, anywhere between a few hundred millivolts on a low-voltage opamp to 25V on an opamp designed for 1kV use.

There may also be some opamps out there which have a minimum supply voltage other than that described above.  If so, I haven't seen one. But it'll say in the datasheet.

The only way to answer this question is to **check the datasheet for the opamp you plan to use**. You can edit your question with the part number or (better) a link to the datasheet if you're not sure how to interpret it. Or, if you haven't picked an opamp yet, buy a rail-to-rail one.

Comment: So in any case, an op amp supplied with less than the maximum supply voltage will still operate properly, but will just clip at a lower voltage?

Comment: Yes. How much lower than the supply depends on the part but up to that point it should work fine. However the supply voltage should always be higher than the input signals unless you've check the datasheet very carefully to make sure you're OK.

Comment: A non rail-to-rail opamp will clip the top and bottom of the waveform to a bit below the positive rail and a bit above the negative rail.  When clipping, the opamp is said to be saturated.  There may be a small delay in leaving saturation, though this will normally only matter at high frequency.